# Can anyone help me to write R scripts which give me top two expressed genes?

Tags: r

I would like to find top two expressed isoforms in a dataset like this:

```
ID         position   count
Gene1,       1300,       200
Gene1,      1400,        54
Gene1,       4500,      178
Gene1,       230,        450
Gene2,       4580,       80
Gene2,       549,        740
Gene2,       84,         199
```

Result should look like this:

```
ID,        position1,   p1-count,   position2,  p2-count
Gene1,       230,          450,       1300,        200
Gene2,       84,           199,       549,         740
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Does that mean you are looking for the top two `count` per `ID`?  We are not all biologists.

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived at the result? Is it just the two lowest values of position?

Comment: Sorry for lack of clear explanation. Program has to check the counts for each ID, pick up top 2 counts, then print ID, position correspond to the highest count, highest count, position correspond to the second highest count and the second highest count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also working on biological data. So I know what you want.

```
d1 <- read.table(text="ID position count
Gene1 1300 200
Gene1 1400 54
Gene1 4500 178
Gene1 230 450
Gene2 4580 80
Gene2 549 740
Gene2 84 199", head=T, as.is=T)

library(dplyr)

d2 <- d1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% arrange(desc(count)) %>%
  do(head(., 2)) %>% group_by(ID)\

d2
# Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
# Groups: ID [2]

#      ID position count
#   (chr)    (int) (int)
# 1 Gene1      230   450
# 2 Gene1     1300   200
# 3 Gene2      549   740
# 4 Gene2       84   199
```

I think the structure of `d2` is pretty good. Anyway, to get your desired result, use `cbind`.

```
cbind(d2[seq(1, nrow(d2), by=2), ], d2[seq(2, nrow(d2), by=2), -1])
#      ID position count position count
# 1 Gene1      230   450     1300   200
# 2 Gene2      549   740       84   199
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ven Yao!